# Using hexdump to replicate xxd command

Tags: shell, hexdump

On my current workstation, I only have `hexdump` and I am not allowed to install other packages such as `xxd`.
So I need to translate this xxd command to an hexdump equivalent

```
echo "my home is very good 002_" | xxd -p -c 256
#Output: 6d7920686f6d65206973207665727920676f6f64203030325f0a


echo "my home is very good 002_" | hexdump -e '256 1 "%x"'
#Output: 6d7920686f6d65206973207665727920676f6f64203030325fa
```

As you can see, there is an extra "0" at the end of the output which means my solution is not working.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `%02x` as the format specifier for hexdump. A single byte would not be zero-prefixed unless you tell it to. Unfortunately, that'll start padding your lines out unless you strip them off.

For example:

```
echo "" | hexdump -e '256 1 "%02x"'
#Output: 0a[followed by a significant amount of whitespace]
```

To match the behavior exactly, you can combine hexdump with `fold`:

```
echo "" | hexdump -e '"%02x"' | fold -b -w512
```